# What are the basic differences between these ways creating and handling arrays?

Tags: iphone, ios, arrays, nsarray

I am unsure which way to declare my arrays with fixed size of 10 objects of type MyClass and what are the implications of these different alternatives for efficiency, ease of coding or anything else.

...keeping in mind the new xCode4.4 features, esp:

- For the NSArray and NSDictionary classes, support is provided for
  Objective-C literals.
- Subscripting using '[ ]' syntax is supported for Objective-C
  container objects.

...and of course using ARC

In particular I need to write contructor methods that return these arrays as a result.

**Alternative1**

```
  MyClass* objectOfMyClass;
  MyClass* array1[10];
  array1[5] = objectOfMyClass;
```

Declaration of method:

```
- (MyClass*[]) createArray {   <--- is this declaration correct like this ?
```

ps. AFAIK these arrays are put on the stack memory - but I am not sure!

**Alternative2**

```
    MyClass* objectOfMyClass;

    NSMutableArray *array2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i = 0; i<10; i++)
        [array2 addObject:objectOfMyClass]; //objects get added in some way...
    //can't directly access nTh object in this case, need to add from 0 to 9
    //conversion to non mutable array, since size will not change anymore
    NSArray *array3 = [NSArray arrayWithArray:array2];
```

Declaration of method:

```
- (NSArray*) createArray {
```

ps. AFAIK these arrays are put in main memory - not stack - but I am not sure!

**Alternative3**

```
NSArray *array4 = [[NSArray alloc] init];
array4 = ...how to prepare the array so it can hold 10 objects without using NSMutableArray ?
            otherwise I do not see a difference to alternative 2...
for (int i = 0; i<10; i++)
    array4[i] = objectOfMyClass];
```

Declaration of method:

```
- (NSArray*) createArray {
```

Many thanks for bringing light into this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a great article about literals [here](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html). You cannot do Alternative 1. The best way to do this is:

```
NSMutableArray *holdsMyClass = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10]; // sized so array does not need to realloc as you add stuff to it
```

You cannot arbitrarily increase the size of the array by indexing past the size - if you have an object at index 5, you can replace it though:

```
holdsMyClass[5] = obj;
```

For example, if you try to compile this, it fails:

```
- (NSArray*[]) createArray
{
    NSArray *foo[10];
    foo[2] = [NSArray array];

    return foo;
}
```

generates this error: "array initializer must be an initializer list"

Comment: thank you very much for the link to the article - really helps to explain what Apple only mentions w/o explaining it - even in the detailed docs about the new Xcode4.4 features. However, I do not understand why you say "cannot do Alternative 1"

Comment: What I meant was that ARC often complains if you mix "C" arrays and objects it manages - it cannot track those objects and thus cannot insure that objects are properly retained and released. I believe this topic is covered in the ARC document on llvm site: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html